# Incorporating Freeform form into an entry

Tags: entries, form

I have constructed a Freeform form, but can't see how to incorporate the form (or a link to it) in an entry.

Please advise.

MTiA

Phil

Answer (score 1):

The most common way would be to create a Freeform Form select field, which allows the entry to select which form it relates to:

[image: A screenshot of the add field settings screen with Freeform Form highlighted]

Add that field to your entry layout (or matrix block type), then in your template you can fetch the form object with `craft.freeform.form(entry.yourFormFieldHandle, {some: freeform, options: here})`.

If you prefer not to allow the entry to change which form is used, you can hardcode the handle into your template.